# Sqlcode of the cursor query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, sqlcode

I have a oracle cursor with query

```
CURSOR cursor IS SELECT column1 FROM table_name WHERE column1 = 48200;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE);
```

I need the SQLCODE of the query in the cursor. I wrote without cursor then i can get the SQLCODE but i need the SQLCODE with the CURSOR.

```
SELECT column1 FROM table_name WHERE column1 = 48200;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE);
```

here I can able to get the SQLCODE as 0 for 'data found' and 100 for 'no data found'

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem you don' t have? You will clearly know if your cursor returned anything when you try to iterate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work for a cursor. You should use `cursor_name%FOUND` or `cursor_name%NOTFOUND` instead.